# codeigniter site stops working if database deleted

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

The other day my colleague accidentally dropped my entire database. This completely disabled the website and just an error message displayed saying;

A DATABASE ERROR OCCURRED.

Error Number: 1146

Table website.news doesn't exist

Technically, my website **does not need** the tables in the database in order to serve it's actual purpose - they just provide a little more information. Is there a way to stop that error from appearing should the database be dropped again? And for my website to continue as normal but just display blank where the content of the database tables would usually appear?

Comment: _"The other day my colleague accidentally dropped my entire database..."_ Hah... I guess that's what db backups are for.

Comment: `The other day my colleague accidentally dropped my entire database. This completely disabled the website` You don't say!

Comment: its because u ve initialized the model which calls that table. that should be your problem

Comment: @SeanWM - turns out my host wasn't running regular backups either! Not a great time to find that out.

Comment: @MikeLovely Ouch. Sorry to hear that.

Comment: @DamienPirsy - I knew that would happen. I just never thought my colleague would be so dumb!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to disable all database calls within your application. In correctly designed Codeigniter app it should be enough to comment (disable) all models usage (within cotroller(s) code), but it depends on your particulat code if this will work.

You investigation can be started from grep "website.news", good luck!